# Rails/Delayed_Job: Restarting delayed job still brings up outdated errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, delayed-job

I had a delayed_job error in an email I was sending ('user' value not found)

I removed the user field from the mailer view, restarted the passenger instance (touch tmp/restart.txt), restarted the delayed_job worker (script/delayed_job restart) and assumed everything would be good to go.

But - I'm still getting the same error message when I send a new mail process to delayed job. (Just to reiterate, this is not the existing error messages staying in the database - when I send a new mail, the same error comes up)

So, it seems delayed job isn't "restarting" quite as much as I'd like it to restart. Any ideas how I can flush out whatever needs flushing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting workers to properly restart has long been an issue because of Delayed Job's reliance on the Daemons gem.  You can read all about it here:

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/3

What's worked for me is to use the ghazel-daemons gem, as discussed in the thread.